# How to stop location services when the app is in background?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, background, location

In my app I load some sites in UIWebView. Some of these sites use location services.

My problem is, that while viewing one of these sites, when the app goes to background, the location services are still on. Since my app didn't turn them on - I don't know what to do.

The current solution I have is loading a blank page when going to background, then loading the original site back when moving to foreground. It works, but the blank page is visible to the user, when viewing the app - which isn't very good.

Does anyone have other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to `location services` in `settings` and turn off any apps using location services. Mine was thumb speak that was running and sucking battery life down.

Answer (score 0):

You can quit the app instead of sending in background. Or you can cancel webView request when the app goes in background.

Comment: Closing the app isn't an option. I thought about using '[webView stopLoading]' when going to background - but the site is already loaded. How can I cancel a request if the page was already loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Is it important that the app remains intact when you return from multitasking ?

If not in 100% , I think you should try to load a blank page just when about to multitask.

When coming back , the user might have a different location fix , so you'll need to refresh the page anyway..

Comment: If you look again at my question, you'll see that that is exactly what I did.
It isn't good enough since you can view the blank page.
I wanted to load the screenshot the app does when going to background, but I found it's location only on the simulator (under snapshots), but not on the device.

Comment: Oops , sorry , guess I didn't pay attention.
But hey, isn't the built in safari app doing exactly the same ?!!?
When returning to a site after X minutes , it usually refreshes the site (starting with... of course... a blank page).

Comment: The Safari does solve it somehow - I guess being Apple help there.... I'm using UIWebView and want to solve it somehow too :-)